# Why does .htaccess automatically changes to .htaccess.txt

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to use mod_rewrite and appache to convert my dynamic URLs in to static ones. Therefore I created a .htaccess file in my root folder that is **c:xampp/htdocs/unnamed**. However whenever i try to rename my text document to `.htaccess` it automatically changes to `.htaccess.txt`. It appears only `.htaccess` in the folder but when i look in the details in the properties menue it is actually `.htaccess.txt`. Does anyone know how do i change it to just `.htaccess`
[image: Screenshot of Properties window]

Comment: It's a Windows-settings problem. Easy workaround: Try doing it from the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because on windows it thinks .htaccess is the name of the file. It considers it to be text. Linux it works differently. It doesn't depend on extensions in Linux.

In order for it to work you just rename the file and remove .txt from it. Then it should work how you like it.

1. Open the file your created in a text editor, just use Notepad.
2. Choose "Save as.." and select "All types (*.*)" next to file type.
3. Then type .htaccess and click on save.

*FYI: I would also turn on showing file extensions if you don't already have that on so you can see what extensions your files have by looking at them in the folder.*

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7

Answer (score 1):

This is because Windows default setting doesn't show the known file extension. You can change that option in the Folder option dialog.

But for easier, just open the command line and rename it by command:

`ren .htaccess.txt .htaccess`

Next time when saving a file, paying attention to the file extension, especially not to save source code as .txt file :).